# Is there a way to configure the warning level for Open Api Analyzers in csproj

Tags: c#, openapi, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Running into an issue where the team is using `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` in the projects and getting a different list of errors on different machines.  Have dug in and determined it is an issue with compiler versions being different (4.0 vs 4.2).  Have used the analysis level & mode settings to try to instruct the compilers to target a certain version of the warning scheme, but still have a few discrepancies related to the Open API Analyzers.
`<IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers>true</IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers>`

Specifically, the machines with 4.2 compiler are reporting errors for API1000 & API1003 that are not showing up at all on the machines with the 4.0 compiler.  Is there a configuration flag I can apply to this analyzer to try to get all the machines reporting the same list of errors?  I would prefer to convince the 4.0 machines to report the errors rather than tell the 4.2 machines to suppress them.

Side note, Corporate security posture in this organization means getting everyone updated to the same compiler version will be a significant PITA and could take weeks.  Hoping there is a way to get there through project configurations.

---

EDIT:
I played a bit more and found that visual studio on the 4.0 machine does detect the warning as a warning when I have the file in question open, but the compiler does not see it as either a warning or an error when executing the build.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting warnings or errors for violations of `API1002` with the following two settings.

```
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors
<IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers>true</IncludeOpenAPIAnalyzers>
```

I do if I add this setting.

```
<WarningsAsErrors>API1002</WarningsAsErrors>
```

So a workaround could involve explicitly adding the rules that you are interested in to the `WarningsAsErrors` property.